# Masking individual rows for CSR SpMV in RISC-V RVV 0.7.1

Tags: vectorization, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, riscv

EDIT: I have reformulated my question into something more productive, and will provide an answer below. The old version of this question is below still.

I am implementing an optimized SpMV kernel for the CSR format in RVV 0.7.1. In C, SpMV can be implemented as such:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    for (int j = rowPtr[i]; j < rowPtr[i+1]; j++)
       y[i] += val[j] * x[colIdx[j]];
```

Vectorizing this is simple initially, by loading `coldIdx`, using it to perform an indexed load of `x`, loading `val` and multiplying the two. After this, a reduction sum (`v{f}redsum.vs`) must be performed in each row, adding all the products within them and storing them in the respective index of `y`. The challenge is creating the mask from `rowPtr`, so that only the elements belonging to a given row are active for each reduction.

My initial thought (which should provide context regarding the original question) was using the indexes in `rowPtr` to place 1's in the respective elements of a vector register, then using `viota` and an element shift to create a register containing the row each element belongs to. However, that is apparently not viable.

How do I build the required masks?

---

**Old question**

*I am trying to use the RISC-V vector extension (0.7.1) to create a mask register based off an array of indices. For example, take the following array of indices, `idx array`. The goal is to use the indices present in it to put 1's in the respective mask elements, as you see with the `mask` below:*

```
idx array | 0 2 3 4 4 6 8
elem idx  | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
mask      | 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

*At first I was mistakenly looking at the `vrgather.vx` instruction, but it does not do quite what I want, as it populates all elements. I would like the code to be quite performant as well, so if it's possible for it consist of mostly vector instructions that would be ideal. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.*

Comment: I don't think this is reasonably possible. Can you share more details of what you want to vectorize, maybe there is another angle to tackle the problem from?

Comment: @camel-cdr The overall goal is vectorizing SpMV in the CSR format. I need to mask the elements of each row for a reduction sum (`redsum`). The idea was to use `viota` after creating that mask register, them using a comparison with an incrementing index to create the final masks.

Comment: I must confess I haven't written SpMV before. But from looking it up, is the part you are talking about this one? `for i from rOff[row] to rOff[row+1]: sum += vals[i] * x[cols[i]];`
wouldn't you only need to mask the contiguous elements from `rOff[row] to rOff[row+1]`? If thats completely of base I probably can't be of much help.

Comment: You're right, the process is 1. loading `vals`, 2. loading `cols`, 3. using `cols` to do an indexed load of `x`, 4. multiplying `vals` and `x`, 5. masking each row and performing a `redsum`. You repeat step 5 for each of the rows, and that's the part that has me stumped, coming up with the mask from `rOff` in an efficient manner. Perhaps I got too fixated on using `viota` and so on to arrive at the mask, other approaches are also valid.

Comment: That should be easy, say you want to mask elements `begin=rOff[row]` to `end=rOff[row+1]` inclusive, then you can create such a mask with: `vmxor(vmsbf(vmseq(vid,begin)), vmsif(vmseq(vid,end)))`. `vmsbf` is set before first bit, and `vmsif` is set including fist bit.
But why don't you just start reading from `begin` and setvl to `end - begin`?
Btw, I'd recommend reducing after the loop is done, as this is usually faster. That is accumulating into all elements of a vector register  with tail undisturbed and reducing once afterward.

Comment: I see, that could certainly work. As for messing with the `vstart` CSR, according to the standard "Traps on vector reduction instructions are always reported with a vstart of 0. Vector reduction operations raise an illegal instruction exception if vstart is non-zero.", so I don't think I can do that.

Comment: Small correction, you want to mask the elements, but not including the end element (which belongs to the next row). I believe it's an easy fix, you simply use `vmsbf` for both instead of `vmsif`

Comment: I didn't mean `vstart`,I was thinking something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/MMj633Kx8), based on an CSR kernel I found online. The autovectorizer already does a good job though. You'd just need to port i to the equivalent rvv 0.7.1 instructions. (Edit: this might not work if you are working with some C906 models, as some don't support 64 bit element types)

Comment: Edit: I'm pretty sure I messed up the increment, this should be better: https://godbolt.org/z/zW8zrY1no

Comment: I understand your approach now, but I am working with an architecture with an extremely long MVL, which is inefficient when working with shorter vectors. Given most sparse matrices have very few elements per row, packing the elements of multiple rows for the loads and multiplication should be more efficient for my use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255883/discussion-between-camel-cdr-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for the solution goes to camel-cdr!

Take the following `rowPtr` array:

`0 2 3 5 7`

Lets consider the third iteration (`[3,5[`), which should be more illustrative. The goal is to arrive at the following mask, enabling elements 3 and 4:

`00011000`

The first step is using `vid` to write each element's index to a vector. With that, we can use `vmseq` (set mask if equal) twice, with elements `i` and `i+1` of `rowPtr`, which will result in two registers like so, with a one in element `rowPtr[i]` or `rowPtr[i+1]`:

```
idx | 01234567
i   | 00010000
i+1 | 00000100
```

Then we can use `vmsbf.m` (set-before-first) on both, which sets all bits before the first active mask bit. By XOR'ing the two, we arrive at the final desired mask:

```
sbf i   | 11100000
sbf i+1 | 11111000
xor     | 00011000
```

By iterating through `rowPtr` and repeating this, it is possible to generate a mask for the elements of each individual row. In short, we can write this operation as:

`vmxor(vmsbf(vmseq(vid,rowPtr[i])), vmsbf(vmseq(vid,rowPtr[i+1])))`